# SQL query to derive average sale of an item

Tags: sql, join, window-functions

Below are two tables. An item is being sold at different values during different periods. I need to calculate average sale of the item. I need to come to an optimal working query. I think the trick would be to map each sales date with their start_date and end_date and multiply the quatity with their respective price for that period and then derive the avergae using the formula total sales amount/ total quatity.

```sql
CREATE TABLE sales(
 item_id varchar(255) ,
 start_date date ,
 end_date date,
 price int 
) ;

insert into sales values 
('mobile','2021-01-01','2021-01-05',500),
('mobile','2021-01-06','2021-01-09',400),
('mobile','2021-01-10','2021-01-15',900) ;



CREATE TABLE item(
 sales_id int,
 item_id varchar(255) ,
 sales_date date ,
 quatity int 
) ;

insert into item values 
(101,'mobile','2021-01-01',10),
(102,'mobile','2021-01-06',20),
(103,'mobile','2021-01-15',30) ;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a window function?  Please edit your question and show the exact results you want for your given sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            select item_id, sum(total_amount)/sum(quatity) avg_price from
            (
            select s.item_id, s.price, i.quatity, s.price * i.quatity as total_amount
            from sales s, item i where i.item_id = s.item_id
            and i.sales_date between s.start_date and s.end_date
            ) as A
            group by item_id;
```

[image]

Comment: will the query work if there are more than one sale happened within a sale period?

Comment: this query is giving correct result !

Comment: but can we solve the same with window function?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
SELECT 
i.item_id,avg(s.price*i.quatity) FROM 
item I 
LEFT JOIN 
sales S
on
I.item_id=S.item_id
AND I.sales_date >=S.start_date AND I.sales_date<=S.end_date
group by i.item_id;
```

Comment: will the query work if there are more than one sale happened within a sale period?

Comment: Yes, it should work